# Excluding a rank while ordering users by rank

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order by users by their xp's while excluding the admins from the resuls.

Admins have the `rights` column equal to `2` in the table.

Higher prestige has better ranking while ordering by xp.

```
select 
a.*,
1 + count(b.username) AS rank 
from `hs_users` as `a` 
left join `hs_users` as `b` 
on 

    `b`.`prestige` = `a`.`prestige` and `b`.`overall_xp` > `a`.`overall_xp` 

    or `b`.`prestige` > `a`.`prestige` 

    and  `b`.`rights` <> `2` 

where `a`.`rights` <> 2 

group by `a`.`username` order by `prestige` desc, `rank` asc
```

This query gives me an error called `Unknown column '2' in 'on clause'.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the backtics from numbers and strings. Backticks are only to escape column names. 
For escaping strings you have to use single qoutes.
At nubers there is no need to escape them.

```
select 
a.*,
1 + count(b.username) AS rank 
from `hs_users` as `a` 
left join `hs_users` as `b` 
on 

    `b`.`prestige` = `a`.`prestige` and `b`.`overall_xp` > `a`.`overall_xp` 

    or `b`.`prestige` > `a`.`prestige` 

    and  `b`.`rights` <> 2

where `a`.`rights` <> 2 

group by `a`.`username` order by `prestige` desc, `rank` asc
```

Comment: Yeah! :D Such foolness from me, thanks a lot mate. :)